# В чем ошибка синтаксиса, и как будет правильно?

Tags: javascript

```
window.setTimeout('document.querySelector("a[href='/collection/local-files']").click();',3000);
```

Вся функция выглядит так:

```
function actionoflocbutt(){
document.querySelector("a[href='/collection']").click();
window.setTimeout('document.querySelector("a[href='/collection/local-files']").click();',3000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что внутри одинарных кавычек используются ещё раз они же. Отчего получается, что закрывается строка, дальше непонятные символы и снова открывается.

Если используются одинарные кавычки внутри одинарных или двойные внутри двойных, то нужно внутренние кавычки экранировать.

```
'document.querySelector("a[href=\'/collection/local-files\']").click();'
                                ^------                  ^-------
```